# Duvida em localizar elemento de array

Tags: php

Fiz este programa em php. A resposta deveria ser "20",  porem ele informa :

> Undefined index: cod_produto in **[...][...]** on line 21</

```
for($i =0; $i < 20; $i++){  
      $valores[] = array (

    $i => 
    array(
        'cod_produto' => $i,
        'valor' => $i*2
    ));

};



$codProcura = 10;
$valor1 = 0;

for($x = 0; $x < 20; $x++){    
    $search = $valores[$x];
    if($valores[$x]['cod_produto'] == $codProcura){///esta eh a linha 21
        $valor1 = $search['valor'];
        break;
    }
}
echo $valor1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Há um problema no momento que você está construindo o *array*. Nesse momento, você cria um novo índice no array `$valores` e, a ele, atribui um array. Esse array, por sua vez, contém um único índice `$i` que contém outro array contendo as informações.

Diminui para 3 o limite superior, veja o resultado.

```php
for($i =0; $i < 3; $i++){
    $valores[] = array(
        $i => 
            array(
                'cod_produto' => $i,
                'valor' => $i*2
            )
    );
};

echo "<pre>"; var_dump($valores); echo "</pre>";
```

Resultado:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["cod_produto"]=>
      int(0)
      ["valor"]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["cod_produto"]=>
      int(1)
      ["valor"]=>
      int(2)
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["cod_produto"]=>
      int(2)
      ["valor"]=>
      int(4)
    }
  }
}
```

De fato, `$valores[$x]` possui outro array de índice `$x`, e esse sim, por sua vez, possui o conteúdo.

---

Sugiro alterar o código para o seguinte e obter o que quer:

```php
for ($i =0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $valores[] = array( // Cria um novo índice e adiciona.
    // $valores[$i] = array( // Esta é outra opção (equivalente)
        'cod_produto' => $i,
        'valor' => $i*2
    );
};

$codProcura = 10;
$valor1 = 0;

for ($x = 0; $x < 20; $x++) {
    $search = $valores[$x];
    if ($valores[$x]['cod_produto'] == $codProcura) {
        $valor1 = $search['valor'];
        break;
    }
}

echo $valor1;
```

Comment: muito bom, era um lapso que não tinha percebido, agradeço imensamente.

Comment: @Silezia, se a resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar.